# Education and knowledge preservation

Tags: education

I have gone through several academic perils to be educated to be what I am today, throughout my 63years old life on the Earth. But with ageing, whatever I learnt also gets forgotten, though the ashes of the fire of knowledge do remain at my useful access. I always wonder how much information to be retained and what to be deleted from my memory! Looking back, I find no stage where I could say it is enough for the rest of my life on the Earth. Is there any global common consensus on this issue available with the planners of future educational institutions and organisations?

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge gets outdated very quickly. So, the role of knowledge in academic education is primarily to provide context for future knowledge rather than something that will be useful on its own. What tends to remain useful longer is skills to acquire or generate new knowledge.

Comment: I disagree with your statement: "So, the role of knowledge in academic education is primarily to provide context for future knowledge rather than something that will be useful on its own. " Education is useless if it doesn't help in judging deciding and activities on a CURRENT situation. Both past and future knowledge are, and their accessibility, variables.

Comment: Education is not applied immediately, but at some point in the future. However, at that time it will be obsolete.